# Working out the Kurtosis

Tags: statistics, time-series

[image]

I'm not able to understand how it is that they got from 3E(e^2at)/E(e^at)^2 to the next line where they got rid of the expectation in both the numerator and the denominator and then simplified to get the final answer which I also don't understand how they simplified from the second last line. So essentially I don't understand how they worked out the expectation of the numerator term and the denominator term.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Recall that the moment generating function $M_X$ of $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is given by $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \exp(\mu t + (1/2) \sigma^2 t^2)$. The last inequality simply follows from the algebraic rule: $e^{x+y} = e^{x}e^{y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$\alpha_t$ has a normal distribution $\mathcal N (\mu,\,\sigma_{\alpha}^2)$, then $e^{\alpha_t}$ has a log-normal distribution with mean $e^{\mu+\sigma^2_{\alpha}/2}$.